# Modem to Router 1 (wired) to Router 2 (wireless) - getting default gateway not available on Router 2

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I have a modem (Non-WiFi) and two routers.

Router 1 is connect via ethernet cable with Modem

I'm trying to extend my WiFi Range using a Router 2 by connecting to Router 1. But when I try to access Internet from second router, it is showing "**default gateway not available**"

**Modem Configuration**

```
IP Address: 192.168.1.251
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
```

**Router 1 Configuration**

```
Internet
IP Address: 192.168.1.1
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.1.251

LAN
192.168.0.1
255.255.255.0

DHCP: Enabled
Default Gateway: 192.168.0.1
```

**Router 2 Configuration**

Enabled WDS Bridging, Connected to Router 1

```
LAN
IP Address: 192.168.0.2
Subnet Mask: 255.255.0.0

DHCP: Disabled
Default Gateway: 192.168.0.2
```

I tried debugging this using PING from router 2

```
PING 192.168.0.1 (Router 1) Worked
PING 192.168.0.101 (Device connected to Router 1) Worked
PING 192.168.1.251 Didn't Work
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the suggestions received from [@Tom Yan](https://superuser.com/users/554702/tom-yan) and [@JW0914](https://superuser.com/users/529800/jw0914)

I have made some changes to router 2 config:

```
LAN
IP Address: 192.168.0.2
Subnet Mask: 255.255.254.0

DHCP: Disabled
Default Gateway: 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: I expect there are multiple problems (but insufficient info to advise). One problem is your netmask for router2.  You likely also have a NAT/routing issue fot reaffic on the reverse path.

Comment: @davidgo I previously had `255.255.255.0` as subnet mask on router 2, I just changed that to the current one thinking that might help.

Comment: @davidgo What all details should I add ?

Comment: Is router 2 configured to work as a switch or what? If it still acts as a router its default gateway (actually a full *WAN* side setting) should be of router 1's LAN subnet.

Comment: If it acts as a switch that is bridged to router 1's LAN, then its client hosts should simply use router 1's LAN side IP as default gateway.

Comment: WiFi AP needs gateway IP `192.168.1.1`, however as @davidgo mentioned, the subnet of the AP includes the subnet of Router 1, which I don't believe is supposed to to be the case with a WiFi AP, as [AFAIK] the WIfI AP needs a separate subnet than the MAIN router it's extending, and it's unlikely you need 65.534 IPs [`256*256-2`].

Comment: @TomYan Router 2 acts a router.  `default gateway should be of router 1's LAN subnet`, then what should be the gateway IP of router 2 ? Is it `192.168.0.1` ?

Comment: @JW0914 I have updated router 2 config. See the edit. It didn't help.

Comment: If router 2 is *really* working as a router (instead of working in AP/switch-only mode or so), then its *WAN* side setting should be like a LAN host of router 1 (i.e. configured with a address in the `192.168.0.0/24` subnet with default gateway being `192.168.0.1`). Then its LAN side should have an address in yet another subnet (e.g. `192.168.2.1/24`), which will be the default gateway configured on *its LAN hosts* (but not itself). The hosts should also be configured/assigned with an address from the `192.168.2.0/24` subnet. (`/24` is basically a synonym to `subnet mask being 255.255.255.0`.)

Comment: Your router manufacturer should have instructions on their support site about how to set up the WiFi AP, and if they don't, look at OpenWrt's WiFi AP wiki and other OEM's support pages